# Can I build a windows executable from kotlin source code?

Tags: kotlin, native

As far as I know, kotlin native allows you to compile kotlin source code to platform specific nativ code, that runs without any virtual machine.
But I don't seem to find any example on how to build a windows executable (.exe) from kotlin source code.
Why is that?
Can you do it or not?

Answer (score 2):

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-get-started.html shows you how to set up a basic Kotlin Native project, and compile it. The only note is that kotlin native will generate a `.kexe`, which is just a renamed `.exe`.